# No route matches [GET] "/say/hello"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've written a very small program to help me learn ruby. Below is the error I get from the server logs.

This is the URL I am trying from browser and followed errors: `localhost:3000/say/hello`

```
Started GET "/say/hello" for 127.0.0.1 at Sun Jun 10 14:28:45 +0800 2012
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/say/hello"):
  actionpack (3.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.5) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  railties (3.2.5) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.5) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.5) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'
  railties (3.2.5) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
  railties (3.2.5) lib/rails/commands.rb:55
  railties (3.2.5) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
  railties (3.2.5) lib/rails/commands.rb:50
  script/rails:6:in `require'
  script/rails:6


  Rendered /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.4ms)
```

## This is my Gemfile content

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.5'
gem 'sqlite3'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

I've had a look at a few other SO threads, but none seem to relate specifically to my problem.

Comment: Include your routes.rb. Like @TaianSu says you probably don't have the non-restful routes set up.

Comment: Currently I don't have anything in routes.rb. But, After I saw the error I tried few but none worked. I tried resources and match. What should my routes.rb contain just to show "Hello World" which I have in my views/hello.rhtml

Answer (score 2):

In your routes.rb you need either:

`match "say/hello" => "myController#myaction"` (replacing controller and action with proper values)

or

`match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'` Which will allow you to use code like: `link_to "hello", :controller => "mycontroller", :action => "myaction"` or enter the URL (like /say/hello)

The former is the preferred method because users cannot go to urls you don't want them to.

Also, your view should be in a subdirectory with the name of the controller that will be using it, not in the actual 'views' directory

EDIT:

Looking at answer below you need to make your file an html.erb not rhtml

Comment: you mean my "hello.rhtml" should be under app/controllers" folder OR it should be under "app/controllers/views/hello.rhtml" ?

Comment: It should be in /views/myController/hello.html.erb (or rhtml, I believe the standard is html.erb)

Comment: Thanks all, I got the result now. Now I understand that the issue was in my routes.rb and file name extension. This works now

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Type `bundle execute rake routes` to list all the routing paths in your application. Check if `:controller=>"say", :action=>"hello"` there.

Also this doesn't follow the restful rules of rails, so you maybe need to uncomment the `match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'`, which at the last line of `config/routes.rb`.

Comment: I tried that and now I am getting error like "Missing template say/hello, application/hello with {:handlers=>[:builder, :coffee, :erb], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en]}. Searched in: * "/Users/<user_id>/Sites/my_app/app/views"

Comment: Than you have to add an 'app/views/hello.html.erb' view file. Which have something like `<%= @your_result_variable_in_controller %>`, The variable name should follow the result of your `hello` method.

Comment: Btw, check [This tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) for rails' restful convention.

Comment: Thanks Tian. The issue was with my entry in routes.rb which has been corrected below as per user Javanut and corrected my file extension to have .erb instead of rhtml.